# How to determine that the value in df has recurrent sequence from 7 and above numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, repeat

I have dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'number': ['1111112357896', '45226212354444', '150000000064', '5485329999999', '4589622567431']})
```

Question:
To find values where value has recurrent sequence from 7 and above numbers

| number | repeat |
| --- | --- |
| 1111112357896 | 0 |
| 45226212354444 | 0 |
| 150000000064 | 1 |
| 5485329999999 | 1 |
| 4589622567431 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df1['repeat'] = df1['number'].str.contains(r'(\d)\1{6}').astype(int)
```

Regex:

```
(\d)     # match and capture a digit
\1{6}    # match the captured digit 6 more times
```

Output:

```
           number  repeat
0   1111112357896       0
1  45226212354444       0
2    150000000064       1
3   5485329999999       1
4   4589622567431       0
```

Comment: *NB. You can get a `UserWarning` but it's safe to ignore.*

Comment: To remove that warning, one can use extract instead of contains `np.where(df1['number'].str.extract(r'(\d)\1{6}').isnull(), 0, 1)` :)

Comment: @PawanJain yes but I dislike the idea of extracting something to discard it immediately after. `str.contains` should be more efficient. But it's a nice workaround.

Comment: Obviously, `contains` is far better for this. I just added that if someone is annoyed with warnings like me, xD

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

```py
def find_repeats(numbers, cutoff=7):
    repeated_numbers = []
    curr_n = None
    count = 0
    for n in str(numbers):
        if n == curr_n:
            count += 1
            continue
            
        if count >= cutoff:
            repeated_numbers.append(curr_n)
        curr_n = n
        count = 1

    # check the end of the string as well
    if count >= cutoff:
        repeated_numbers.append(curr_n)
        
    return len(repeated_numbers)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'number': ['1111112357896', '45226212354444', '150000000064', '5485329999999', '4589622567431']})
df1['repeat'] = df1.number.apply(find_repeats)
```